# How do I delete a text channel using Java Discord API?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am trying to make a discord bot using JDA (Java Discord API). I’m just wondering how I would delete a text or voice channel using a command? I have a onMessageRecieved listener that works looking for the command, but when I can’t seem to delete the channel using it.

I’ve tried to get the channel by ID and delete it with ‘.delete()’ but with no results.

```
e.getGuild().getChannelByID(e.getChannel().getID()).delete();
```

Comment: What happens when you call delete?  Is an exception thrown?  According to the docs the logged in account needs to have MANAGE_CHANNEL permission.

Comment: No exception is thrown, the account has every permission. Solved because I wasn’t calling a rest action after .delete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using returns an instance of RestAction.
In order to execute action, you have to call one of the execution methods queue()/complete()/submit().

```
 e.getGuild().getChannelByID(e.getChannel().getID()).delete().reason(reason).queue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!